# Beautify json data being printed on android studio's debug console

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, debugging, logging

I am developing flutter applications and all of my API responses are in Json. While debugging, printing these long arrays of Json data to the android Studio console makes it very hard to cross-check the content. Is there any possible way to beautify these logs as they are being printed to console?

Comment: Did you tried the inbuild log?

```import 'dart:developer';

log('your statement here'); ```

Answer (score 0):

try to use `log()` function from `dart:developer`.

and as you know you can use `print()` too but print function has a limit to show the characters and if your response is too long it misses some lines of response but log function is better.

happy coding...